# App is crashing on some devices with android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My app is crashing on some devices with an error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException. After looking up in Android Vitals Crashes section, the following function is causing it to crash:

```
private void openUrl(String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

It is an intent to open play store page of my app with url as my play store app link.
I couldn't able to reproduce the crash in any of my devices. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: before calling you should check intent resolution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677368/3056090

Comment: whats your target sdk version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that any given `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` will work. For example, the active user may have a restricted profile or be part of some work profile where they lack access to whatever it is that you are trying to start.

The safest solution, with Android 11 in mind, is to catch the exception:

```java
private void openUrl(String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    try {
      startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // do something to tell the user "sorry!"
    }
}
```