# Unclear about how to use resolveActivity() in the Intent class (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am unsure about the purpose of the `resolveActivity` method in the `Intent` class, based on the docs the `resolveActivity` method "returns the Activity component that should be used to handle this intent"

Since my `Intent` instance has `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` as it's parameter, the getAction() is non null and the `intent` must be handled by the `Activity`. I don't see the purpose in using `actionView.resolveActivity(packageManager)`.

```
val actionView = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, currentUri) //Creation of the Intent Object

actionView.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.run {  //Checking if the resolveActivity instance is null
    ...}
```

Comment: You can use it and check for non-null result to know whether it's safe to call `startActivity` with that same intent. Otherwise, I think the actual result has questionable usefulness. There might be multiple possible components that can handle the intent, and so you usually don't want to just use the first one that pops up. That's sort of like clicking "I'm feeling lucky" on google.com. Better to let the user decide if there are multiple choices.

Comment: here is more about resolveIntent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676934/what-exactly-is-intent-resolveactivitygetpackagemanager-doing